# How to compare two files and get search string column and row details using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working pandas project. I am pretty new to it,  I have two  huge data frame which has structure similar to bellow

Data frame 1:

```html
Animals       Plants                
Dog         Amaryllis                
Cat         Angel Wing Begonia       
Dragon      African Violet
```

Data frame 2:

```html
Animals           Planents    Amaryllis   Angel Wing Begonia
Dog              Earth          x                x
Cat              Pluto          na               na
Dragon           Mars           na               x
```

I need all the plants form dataframe1 to be compared with 'x' values in the dataframe2 , if 'x' is present the particular column , I have to pick column name (ex:Amaryllis is present in first row )  , animal name , planet name and write them into other file .

Expected output :

```html
Amaryllis             , Dog,    Earth
Angel wing Begonia    , Dog,    Earth
Angel wing Begonia    , Dragon,  Mars
```

Currently I have tried just reading column with x value

```html
DATA = df_xlsx[df_xlsx['Amaryllis'].str.contains('X', na=False)]
    
DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the significance of `df1`. As far as I can see, it looks like a `melt/stack` and filter:

```
(df2.melt(['Animals','Planents'], var_name='Plants')
    .query('value=="x"')
    .iloc[:,:-1]
)
```

Output:

```
  Animals Planents              Plants
0     Dog    Earth           Amaryllis
3     Dog    Earth  Angel Wing Begonia
5  Dragon     Mars  Angel Wing Begonia
```